# C++ strtok cant get 2 token Borland

Tags: c++, c++builder, strtok

```
char *ParseCmdX(char *buf,int len)  
{  
 char *p;  
 p = strtok(buf," ,");  
 p = strtok(NULL," ,");  
 char *ptr = (char *)malloc(strlen(p)+1);  
 strcpy(ptr,p);  
 return ptr;  
}
```

Why am I getting an Access Violation error at `p = strtok(NULL," ,");` ?
When I put NULL parameter it breaks ...

buf is smth like "das sdg hfg jgh"

Comment: what does a value in "buf" look like?

Comment: "das gfd jgh khh"  - buf

Comment: @Hak you tagged this as c++ but you're using things like `malloc`, `char *` and `strcpy`. Is there a reason you're doing it this way instead of using strings and smart pointers?

Answer (score 1):

How are you calling this function, and how is buf allocated?  Remember buf cannot be read-only or const (strtok changes the input buffer as it's called).

This works, because x is changable:

```
  char x[] = "das sdg hfg jgh";
  char *c = ParseCmdX(x, strlen(x));
```

This, however, seg faults:

```
   char *y = "das sdg hfg jgh";
   char *c = ParseCmdX(y, strlen(y));
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to check and see if the first call to strtok, namely, strtok(but, " ,") returned NULL or not, if it did then the next call to strtok will die.   what specifically are you passing to the ParseCmdX in buf?

Comment: why it should return NULL ? if i put string like "asd hfdkj gdhk fhjsk"

Comment: Ahmed is exactly correct.  for "das sdg hfg jgh" has no " ," in it, so p is NULL.  Once p is null, there is nothing else to return, so the next strtok call would be moving off the end of the string.  Bang, Nasal Demons everywhere :)

Comment: If the requested token is not found, and the null terminator has not been reached yet, `strtok()` does not return NULL, it returns the remaining portion of the input string up to the null terminator. Besides that, the second parameter of `strtok()` is a *set* of 1-char delimiters. In this case, it will search for `' '` OR `','` characters individually. The `','` character does not exist in the string, but `' '` does, so `strtok()` would not return NULL anyway.  I think Joe is right.  The input string is likely read-only, so strtok() is crashing when it inserts a null character into the string.